# how to give a command to not follow a class in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have a navigation bar and another feature(todolist),  in my HTML code that have something called "li" in common. The javascript has "li" and it affects my navigation system as well. Even setting different classes to the nav bar and todolist, the javascript doesn't seem to work. Is there any sort of code to prevent the javascript from affecting the navigation bar

I have tried using this code to prevent it from recognising the first class:

```
var noGo = document.getElementsByClassName ("container");
```

it stopped the entire function from happening as a whole

Comment: You are probably thinking the wrong way. Instead of selecting a wide variety of HTML nodes, then filtering them. Try to set a more specific class on your HTML and select more specific in JS.

Comment: Provide a [mcve]

Answer (score -1):

you do not always need to call `getElementsByClassName` on `document`, you call it on specific elements also, to get its work on its descendants only.

if i have not misunderstood, you need `container` inside `feature`, so firstly get your `feature` element somehow (probably using `id` attribute i.e., `var feature = document.getElementById("feature");`) and then:

```
var noGo = feature.getElementsByClassName("container");
```

although, comment by Sven van de Scheur, is the best option

i hope it helped :)